# Import Wordpress header / footer into an external page(s)

Tags: php

I have an external forum application, which has an option to include a header and footer as HTML.

In theory I could use HTML to create the header, but this would be very hard to keep up to date, even if it is possible.

Is there any simple way to include the header / footer into the external software?

Comment: this depends greatly on the software you're trying to include it in, it's very unlikely there's a simple straight forward solution, e.g. if you can't execute PHP in your forums template then that eliminates a large number of solutions immediatley. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really given enough information to know what options you have within the software.  You may be able to use a setting or hook into the loading of your forum.
But, if not, perhaps you could use a combination of html, jquery and ajax to solve this.

In your header/footer you could just hold a div

> `<div id='my-header-customization'></div>`

In your js, you could find this and replace the content

> `let myContent = 'you can pull this using ajax';`
>
> `getElementById('my-header-customization').innerHTML = myContent;`

Then in your PHP you could setup your AJAX to pull the content from static text, db, etc.

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782230/ajax-passing-data-to-php-script

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but certainly not a simple process. I've done this with a few applications including WHMCS and it required connecting to the WP database by calling on `wp-config.php` to retrieve credentials. From there it's a collection of DB queries for the needed content and template values. Then follows the formatting methods to put it all together as HTML.

Another method I experimented was to have a method in WP to create PHP files with HTML output of head and foot in a folder by way of `cron`, then call the files via `include` into the external application. This was simpler but lacked flexibility.

Here is my WP database connection method which is part of a class and used privately. It may help you get to where you want, assuming you have some advanced knowledge of PHP.

The constant `WP_PATH` has to be defined based on your file environment.

```php
private static function db($q)
{
    $conf = file(WP_PATH.'/wp-config.php');
    
    $const = [];
    foreach($conf as $v) {
        if( strstr($v, 'DB_NAME') )
            $const['dbname'] = gis($v, "define( 'DB_NAME', '","' );");
        if( strstr($v, 'DB_USER') )
            $const['dbuser'] = gis($v, "define( 'DB_USER', '","' );");
        if( strstr($v, 'DB_PASSWORD') )
            $const['dbpwd'] = gis($v, "define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '","' );");
        if( strstr($v, 'DB_HOST') )
            $const['dbhost'] = gis($v, "define( 'DB_HOST', '","' );");
        if( strstr($v, 'table_prefix') )
            $const['dbprefix'] = gis($v, "table_prefix = '","';");
    }
    
    $db = makeobj($const);
    $dbo = new mysqli($db->dbhost, $db->dbuser, $db->dbpwd, $db->dbname);
    
    if( $dbo->connect_error ) {
        echo '<p style="color:red">DB connection failed: ('.$dbo->connect_errno.') '.$dbo->connect_error.'<br>Database connection was blocked</p>';
        exit();
    }
    
    $q = preg_replace('/\#__/', $db->dbprefix, $q);
    $dbobj = $dbo->query($q);
    $result=[];
    if( $dbobj->num_rows > 0 ) {
        while($row = $dbobj->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $result[] = $row;
        }
    }
    $dbo->close();
    
    return $result;
}

// common function
/**
Get Inner String
filter string between defined characters
gis('/home/name/src/file.php', 'home/', '.php');
value = name/src/file
*/
function gis($string, $start, $end) 
{
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

// array convert to object
function makeObj($data) {
    if( empty($data) )
        return;
    
    return json_decode(json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
}
```

Query methods are standard SQL

`self::db('SELECT * FROM #__posts');` The hash with double underscore is a placeholder for the table prefix which is replace by the function